# Vantiv Magento(eprotect) adding fonts and credit card images?

Tags: magento, iframe

1) Vantiv Magento trying to add Visa, master, discover card images. Please see below screenshot. Is there a option in config to get suck look in iframe?

[image: Credit Card icons below input field with animation as payment bridge]

2) Can we use our typekit fonts they don't work inside iframes is there some domain we can add to enable our fonts so we can provide css? If not what all fonts are available to be used?

Appreciate your help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eProtect Integration Guide states:

> Before you begin using the iFrame solution, you must create a
>   Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) to customize the look and feel of the
>   iFrame to match your checkout page, then submit the style sheet to
>   Vantiv, where it will be tested before it is deployed into production.

The document also notes:

> **Font Library and Icons** - Vantiv hosts SVG Icons (Font ‘Awesome’) font
>   library on our servers for you to leverage in your CSS, using an
>   industry standard icon library for all icons.

There's also a blacklist of CSS that's not allowed; I'm reasonably sure that anything that might point to your domain is prohibited because it's contrary to the PCI scope reduction intent of such a blacklist.

If you haven't already done so, you need to create an account at [Vantiv O.N.E.](https://developer.vantiv.com/) and make use of the documentation there.

Answer (score 0):

You can only change styles of an iFrame if the iFrame's domain is the same as the URL in the browser. Which most likely it isn't in your case. There are some workarounds posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe), so maybe those will help in your quest. Good luck!